# Is there a way to keep youtube_dl from printing its status to the console?

Tags: python, logging, youtube-dl

When I use the [youtube_dl](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/) library in a Python script to download a video, it prints the following in the console:

```
[youtube] [video]: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video [video] because of --no-playlist
[download] Destination: [destination]
[download] 100% of 3.00MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Post-process file [destination] exists, skipping
```

Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

`youtube_dl` doesn't seem to use the standard Python `logging` library, so I can't do this:

```
youtube_logger = logging.getLogger('youtube_dl')
youtube_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Is there any way to keep `youtube_dl` from printing to the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out there's an option called [Quiet Mode](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L151) that does just this! Here's how it works:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'quiet': True
}

youtube_dl_manager = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
```

And then you can use the `YoutubeDL` object normally, without it printing to the console!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the quiet option:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'quiet': True
}


youtube_dl_manager = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
```

Comment: I was looking through the library, trying to figure out how to do what you said, when I came across something called "quiet mode". Turns out there's an option I can use when creating the `YoutubeDL` object that stops it from printing its messages! Perfect!

Comment: P.S. his answer was inspired from mine. plz no downvotes.

Comment: You know you can see the edit history of the answer, right? https://i.imgur.com/SHxaMZY.png

Comment: yes, but not that many people look at that, so I gave them a hint.